# Java keystore Iterating over Windows-MY without using aliases

Tags: java, iteration, keystore

Is there any way to iterate over the Windows-MY keystore without using the enumeration of the aliases. The problem I have is that I have a smartcard which has two certificates on it with the same alias, so when I try to load the second certificate I get the first one again.
Currently I iterate over the certificates like so:

```
try {
        KeyStore oks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", MSProvider);
        oks.load(null, null);
        for (Enumeration l = oks.aliases(); l.hasMoreElements();) {
            certCount++;
            String al = (String) l.nextElement();
            Certificate cert = oks.getCertificate(al);//<<returns the same cert twice
            //do stuff
        }
```

Any help gratefully received.

Ok so it turns out this is a known bug in the Java Microsoft CryptoAPI KeyStore implementation where the friendly name only is used as an alias - see
[here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6672015).

The link also contains the solution I've added below in case the link goes down

Comment: That doesn't sounds very smart to me. :) A (very) crude solution would be to create a copy of the keystore first (using `KeyStore.store()`, then delete the first alias to get to the second one.

Comment: @biziclop I should add I didn't create the smartcard... I'll give your suggestion a go

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you did. It was just an inane joke.

Comment: @biziclop No offence taken ;). My reply was supposed to be jokey to. Anyway I tried your suggestion but Keystore.store seems to have a problem copying the store as it throws a  KeyStoreException: Keyset does not exist when I try to delete the entry. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I found as mentioned in the question above is from [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6672015).

It involves using reflection to create a unique alias.

```
private static void _fixAliases(KeyStore keyStore) {
    Field field;
    KeyStoreSpi keyStoreVeritable;

    try {
        field = keyStore.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyStoreSpi");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        keyStoreVeritable = (KeyStoreSpi)field.get(keyStore);

        if("sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore$MY".equals(keyStoreVeritable.getClass().getName())) {
            Collection entries;
            String alias, hashCode;
            X509Certificate[] certificates;

            field = keyStoreVeritable.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getDeclaredField("entries");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            entries = (Collection)field.get(keyStoreVeritable);

            for(Object entry : entries) {
                field = entry.getClass().getDeclaredField("certChain");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                certificates = (X509Certificate[])field.get(entry);

                hashCode = Integer.toString(certificates[0].hashCode());

                field = entry.getClass().getDeclaredField("alias");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                alias = (String)field.get(entry);

                if(!alias.equals(hashCode)) {
                    field.set(entry, alias.concat(" - ").concat(hashCode));
                } // if
            } // for
        } // if
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        System.err.println(exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } // catch
} // _fixAliases
```