# Microsoft CryptoAPI KeyStore unique alias on Java 17 without --add-opens

Tags: java, cryptoapi, java-17

When using Java 8 and trying to access Microsoft CryptoAPI KeyStore (msCAPI) there was the issue of potential alias duplicates. That is, you could have two certificates with the same alias, making one inaccessible.

For Java 8 the workaround was this ([StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591656/2732991), [Java.com bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6672015)):

```java
private static void _fixAliases(KeyStore keyStore) {
    Field field;
    KeyStoreSpi keyStoreVeritable;

    try {
        field = keyStore.getClass().getDeclaredField("keyStoreSpi");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        keyStoreVeritable = (KeyStoreSpi)field.get(keyStore);

        if("sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore$MY".equals(keyStoreVeritable.getClass().getName())) {
            Collection entries;
            String alias, hashCode;
            X509Certificate[] certificates;

            field = keyStoreVeritable.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getDeclaredField("entries");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            entries = (Collection)field.get(keyStoreVeritable);

            for(Object entry : entries) {
                field = entry.getClass().getDeclaredField("certChain");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                certificates = (X509Certificate[])field.get(entry);

                hashCode = Integer.toString(certificates[0].hashCode());

                field = entry.getClass().getDeclaredField("alias");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                alias = (String)field.get(entry);

                if(!alias.equals(hashCode)) {
                    field.set(entry, alias.concat(" - ").concat(hashCode));
                } // if
            } // for
        } // if
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        System.err.println(exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } // catch
} // _fixAliases
```

With Java 17 came [JEP 403](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403), which now causes the `field.setAccessible(true)` to give a stack similar to this:

```
14:17:53.916 [main] ERROR System.err - java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.security.KeyStoreSpi java.security.KeyStore.keyStoreSpi accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @4206a205
14:17:53.916 [main] ERROR System.err -  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
14:17:53.916 [main] ERROR System.err -  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
14:17:53.916 [main] ERROR System.err -  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
14:17:53.916 [main] ERROR System.err -  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
...
```

This leaves me with one workaround of adding `--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED` to the VM options.

**Is there some cleaner way to deal with this in JDK17, to not undo JDK encapsulation?**